# reading simple text file into R - BLS data

Tags: r, read.table

I'm trying to understand how to read some text files from the BLS database into R.

```
url <- "http://download.bls.gov/pub/time.series/oe/oe.datatype"
datatype <- read.table(url)
Error in scan(file, what, nmax, sep, dec, quote, skip, nlines, na.strings, :line 1 
did not have 6 elements
```

I also tried:

```
datatype <- read.table(url, header = FALSE)
Error in scan(file, what, nmax, sep, dec, quote, skip, nlines, na.strings,  
:line 1 did not have 6 elements
```

And:

```
datatype <- read.table(url, sep="\t")
```

This last method almost works, but when I examine the data frame, it looks like the first column has been converted into row names, and the last column is filled with NA's.

```
datatype
                          datatype_code datatype_name
01                                 Employment            NA
02 Employment percent relative standard error            NA
03                           Hourly mean wage            NA
04                           Annual mean wage            NA
```

I also tried to download and examine the file, but am not sure what I am looking at in Notepad++.

```
download.file(url, "datatype.txt")
datatype <- read.table("datatype.txt", sep='\t')

datatype
                                datatype_code datatype_name
01                                 Employment            NA
02 Employment percent relative standard error            NA
03                           Hourly mean wage            NA
04                           Annual mean wage            NA
```

Thanks for any tips. Just trying to learn.

Comment: This one almost works, drops the headers: `data.table::fread("http://download.bls.gov/pub/time.series/oe/oe.datatype", colClasses = rep("character",3))[,1:2, with = FALSE]`. These files are strange, every row has extra tab character at the end, apart from the header.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the extra tab character not being there on the header row. Helps me understand the why part of the error I was getting.

Answer (score 2):

As pointed out by @zx8754, this particular file has an extra tab character "\t" in each row with the exception of the header row.

You could read the file without the header:

```
url <- "http://download.bls.gov/pub/time.series/oe/oe.datatype"
df <- read.delim(url, skip = 1, header = FALSE)
head(df)
#   V1                                         V2 V3
# 1  1                                 Employment NA
# 2  2 Employment percent relative standard error NA
# 3  3                           Hourly mean wage NA
# 4  4                           Annual mean wage NA
# 5  5       Wage percent relative standard error NA
# 6  6                Hourly 10th percentile wage NA
```

You could also read in the first row for the headers separately:

```
header <- read.delim(url, nrows = 1, header = FALSE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
names(df) <- header
head(df)
#   datatype_code                              datatype_name NA
# 1             1                                 Employment NA
# 2             2 Employment percent relative standard error NA
# 3             3                           Hourly mean wage NA
# 4             4                           Annual mean wage NA
# 5             5       Wage percent relative standard error NA
# 6             6                Hourly 10th percentile wage NA
```

At this point you'd probably want to remove the third column:

```
df <- df[-3]
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. I was able to manually add the tab character at the end of the file I downloaded, but with your tip I can just adjust my script and avoid having to manually adjust anything. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Here is a tidyverse option that worked great. It turns out that readr::read_tsv handles this efficiently.

```
library(tidyverse)
df <- read_tsv(url)
head(df)
# A tibble: 6 x 2
  datatype_code                              datatype_name
          <chr>                                      <chr>
1            01                                 Employment
2            02 Employment percent relative standard error
3            03                           Hourly mean wage
4            04                           Annual mean wage
5            05       Wage percent relative standard error
6            06                Hourly 10th percentile wage
```

Comment: Thanks Ben. I was actually revisiting this problem again recently. The tidyverse readr functions do work well. Out of curiosity, are you getting a bunch of warning messages though?

Comment: I do but I believe they are part of the parsing process. See the vignette and >problems(df) for more. I am unable to explain it, however.